# How to change AWS S3 bucket long URL to short S3 URL when hosting a static website?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-hosting

Team,

I need to change the AWS S3 URL to a shorter URL version, example:

Current: **https://trabajos-costa-rica.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/index.html**

Need to change to: **https://s3.amazonaws.com/trabajos-costa-rica/index.html**

This is working on thousands of websites/buckets but I'm not able to find the right configuration, I'm hosting a static HTML website on Amazon S3.

This a live working example:

**https://s3.amazonaws.com/walgreens-photo-coupon/walgreens/index.html**

**https://s3.amazonaws.com/orlando-cremation-services/average-cost-of-cremation-in-orlando-florida-call-us-at-407-250-9846-2.html**

**https://s3.amazonaws.com/dfc_attachments/public/documents/3260209/Dental_Plan_Overview_2019.pdf**

How this was done it's the question?

I'm getting the following error:

```
<Error>
<Code>PermanentRedirect</Code>
<Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message>
<Endpoint>trabajos-costa-rica.s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
<Bucket>trabajos-costa-rica</Bucket>
<RequestId>C8632DF84734CE4A</RequestId>
<HostId>KyFNBQtuz2pwDPBMquz72kvozKWHOB3uN1ctiSKtuxvBqSvh9AaRISIQlqelOelLlQITGQCAwBs=</HostId>
</Error>
```

but I wonder if this is a generic error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
https://s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/trabajos-costa-rica/index.html
```

Note that it **includes the region name**.

However, please note that this style of accessing Amazon S3 buckets is about to be **turned off for new buckets**. After September 30, 2020 only the virtual-host style of naming will be available:

```
https://trabajos-costa-rica.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html
```

See: [Amazon S3 Path Deprecation Plan – The Rest of the Story | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/)

You can also use your own domain name on Amazon S3 buckets. See: [Configuring a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I understand that feature will be deprecated in 2 weeks, however, do you know what settings are needed on AWS to set up this URL: **https://s3.amazonaws.com/trabajos-costa-rica/index.html**

Comment: Not sure, but it will work if you use `s3-us-east-2` instead of just `s3`.